# Using sexplib for serializing Ocaml types

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to use sexplib to serialize and deserialize a custom ocaml record type which has an inline definition as follows

```
type eff = Add of {username: string; pwd: string}
| AddFollowing of {leader_id: id}
| RemFollowing of {leader_id: id}
| AddFollower of {follower_id: id}
| RemFollower of {follower_id: id} 
| Blocks of {follower_id: id}
| GetBlocks
| IsBlockedBy of {leader_id: id}
| GetIsBlockedBy
| GetInfo
| GetFollowers
| GetFollowing [@@deriving sexp]
```

When I try to compile this using `ocamlfind ocamlc -package sexplib,ppx_sexp_conv -linkpkg microblog_app.ml` I get the error `Failure("Pcstr_record not supported")
File "microblog_app.ml", line 1:
Error: Error while running external preprocessor`.

I saw that ppx_sexp_conv doesn't support inline definitions in their current release. Unfortunately I can't use their development release since it would 
cause a version conflict with my other packages. So I tried to change the inline definition as follows

```
type usernamePwd = {username: string; pwd: string}
type leaderId = {leader_id: id}
type followerId = {follower_id: id}
type eff = Add of usernamePwd
| AddFollowing of leaderId
| RemFollowing of leaderId
| AddFollower of followerId
| RemFollower of followerId
| Blocks of followerId
| GetBlocks
| IsBlockedBy of leaderId
| GetIsBlockedBy
| GetInfo
| GetFollowers
| GetFollowing [@@deriving sexp]
```

I only use the functions `sexp_of_eff` and `eff_of_sexp` in my later code. When I compile this I get the error `Error: Unbound value usernamePwd_of_sexp`. I don't at all use this function in my code. Can someone please tell me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[@@deriving sexp]` annotation you added generates some code that calls `usernamePwd_of_sexp` (due to the way ppx works, it cannot know whether this function exists or not, so it relies on its existence).

This function does not exist. You can create it by adding `[@@deriving sexp]` to the `usernamePwd` declaration (and other types).

An alternative is to make your type declaration recursive (`type usernamePwd = ... and leaderId = ... and type eff = ... [@@deriving sexp]`).